# Apply Borders to Used Range when First Column has no data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel (365) spreadsheet that Column A and Column B have no data as they will be filled in by a Vendor after we send it to them. My last Column in the Spreadsheet is Column O and I would like to apply borders to all cells in the used range but my code applies borders past the used range in Columns A through O because there is no data for Columns A & B.

I am editing some code I found and am close but no cigar yet.

```
Sub TestBorder()
Dim iRange As Range
Dim LastRow as Integer
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet
   Set iRange = .UsedRange.Cells(.UsedRange.Cells.Count)
   With .Range("A:O"), iRange).Borders

Set iRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Offset(1, 1)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `With .Range("A:O"), iRange).Borders` gives compiler error

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting an error as it works on my end (other than apply borders to entire spreadsheet). I did add in the Sub() name and End Sub to the code I posted though in case that is needed

Comment: Note that `UsedRange` does not necessarily correspond to cells with values. If you need to find the [last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba), it's better to do that explicitly instead of relying on `UsedRange`.

Comment: Thank you for this. The worksheet will always have different amounts of rows, so I cannot set a range of let's say "A1:O1100")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestBorder()

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        With .Range("A1:O" & LastRow).Borders()
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked beautifully!!! Thank you SO much! I am taking a few classes to become a better vba/macro developer and contributors like you are such a great help. Again, thank you :)

Comment: @debinsky Note - would be better with `Dim LastRow As Long` in case you ever have more than 32,767 lines the limit for Integer.

Comment: Thank God, it will never be more than 2,000 records. I will make note of your comment though because as we all know...you give someone a good macro and they ask you for more, LOL

Comment: @debinsky - you should definitely change to `As Long`. There's [no benefit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long) to using `Integer`, only downsides.

Answer (score 0):

The below code puts a border around the used range.
The code you posted also includes an Offset and something to do with the range `A:O`, but it is unclear from the question what relevance these would have to the process?

```vb
Dim iRange As Range
With ActiveSheet
    Set iRange = Union(.Range("A:O"), .UsedRange.Columns)
    With iRange.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With 'iRange
End With 'ActiveSheet
```

Comment: If I just call the Used Range, it is not applying the border to columns A and B because the cells below the Header names are blank. With the code I posted above, it applies borders to Columns A through O; however the borders are for the whole worksheet and not just until the data ends on Row 1100 (Columns C through Column O have data whereas Column A and B only have Headers/Column names).

I hope I am explaining correctly.

Comment: OK, I will edit my answer to the UsedRange columns plus A:O columns